# MethodAccessException using merged Server Management Object (SMO) dll

Tags: c#, dll, smo, ilmerge

Currently I am using SMO objects to read Server, Database and Table properties of an SQL server. Properties like version, install date, size, etc. The client computer (there will be multiple) will access the server remotely, but it will not have access to the SMO libraries. For this reason I've been asked to merge the dll files into a carrier dll which is to be deployed at the client computer. I hove no further control of what programs are installed there.

When the code is not running, i get no errors from the merged dll, but when it is run, I get a Method Access Exception (see below).

My Question is this: Is it possible to merge the SMO dlls into a single dll and maintain functionality, or am I beter off adding the dlls seperately. Or is there a beter way to give the client computer access to the SMO functionality?

I'm worried that perhaps it's not possible to merge the SMO dll files into a project and another solution needs to be made, but any ideas to solve my problem is greatly appreciated.

I am using the 32 bit SMO dlls.

The exception message:

```
Attempt by method 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.ObjectLoadInfoManager.LoadHierarchy()' to access method 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.UnSafeInternals.ManagementUtil.EnterMonitor(System.Object)' failed.
```

The stack trace:

```
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.ObjectLoadInfoManager.LoadHierarchy() in DummyClass.cs:line0 
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.ObjectLoadInfoManager.GetFirstObjectLoadInfo(Urn urn, Object ci) in DummyClass.cs:line0 
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.ObjectCache.LoadFirstElementVersionless(Urn urn, Object ci) in DummyClass.cs:line0
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetServerVersion(Urn urn, Object ci) in DummyClass.cs:line0
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetObjectInfo(Object ci, RequestObjectInfo req) in DummyClass.cs:line0
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.GetObjectInfo(Object connectionInfo, RequestObjectInfo requestObjectInfo) in DummyClass.cs:line0
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.FixPropertyList(Object connectionInfo, Urn urn, String[] fields, RequestFieldsTypes requestFieldsType) in DummyClass.cs:line0
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.GetData(Object connectionInfo, Request request) in DummyClass.cs:line0
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.GetEnumeratorDataReader(Request req) in DummyClass.cs:line0
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.GetInitDataReader(String[] fields, OrderBy[] orderby) in DummyClass.cs:line0
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.ImplInitialize(String[] fields, OrderBy[] orderby) in DummyClass.cs:line0
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.Initialize(Boolean allProperties) in DummyClass.cs:line0
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.OnPropertyMissing(String propname, Boolean useDefaultValue) in DummyClass.cs:line0
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.PropertyCollection.RetrieveProperty(Int32 index, Boolean useDefaultOnMissingValue) in DummyClass.cs:line0
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.PropertyCollection.GetValueWithNullReplacement(String propertyName, Boolean throwOnNullValue, Boolean useDefaultOnMissingValue) in DummyClass.cs:line0
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.PropertyCollection.GetValueWithNullReplacement(String propertyName) in DummyClass.cs:line0
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server.get_NetName() in DummyClass.cs:line0
at DummyLibrary.someclass.GetNetName() in DummyClass.cs:line0
at DummyLibrary.someotherclass.GatherSQLBlaBla(YetAnotherClass classvariable, List`1 customerErrorMessages) in DummyClass.cs:line0
at DummyLibrary.StillAnotherClass.GetTheStuff(String stringvar, Int64 aninteger) in DummyClass.cs:line0
at DummyProgram.Main(String[] args) in hubbabubba.Program.cs:line 37
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

My merge string:

```
"$(SolutionDir)packages\ILMerge.2.13.0307\ILMerge.exe" /log:log.txt /target:library /closed /out:"$(ProjectDir)bin\$(Configuration)\DummyOutPut.dll"  "$(ProjectDir)bin\$(Configuration)\DummyInput.dll"  "$(ProjectDir)SmoDll\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll" "$(ProjectDir)SmoDll\Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll" "$(ProjectDir)SmoDll\Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll" "$(ProjectDir)SmoDll\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll" "DummyPath\log4net.dll"
```

If the dlls are not merged but referenced as external dlls, no errors occur. I did find this worrying log line in the ilmerge log:

```
Duplicate type name: modifying name of the type 'AssemblyVersionInfo' (from assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc') to 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc1173.AssemblyVersionInfo'
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you can use the SMO object library, the 'Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types' library is also required. We had a change of plan, and we are now preforming an install of the two msi files.